# Как использовать оператор LIKE в параметризованном запросе используя библиотеку pymysql?

Tags: python, mysql, параметры, pymysql, like

Оператор LIKE использует спецсимвол % как элемент регулярного выражения, например:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE bday_at LIKE '20%'
```

Этот же символ используется в библиотеке pymysql, при использовании параметризованных параметров, например:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO messages (from_user_id, message) VALUES (%(id)s, %(text)s);', {'id': id, 'text': text})
```

Как быть, если нужно подставлять параметр в регулярное выражение оператора LIKE? Приведённый ниже код не работает, как и все вариации на тему, что удалось придумать.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM activities WHERE name LIKE %%(mark)s%;", {'mark': mark.lower()})
```

Можно конечно использовать f-строки и подставлять нужную часть непосредственно в запрос, но это плохая практика с точки зрения безопасности.

Comment: А если этот символ экранирован? `.. LIKE \%%(mark)s\%; ..`? если не работает - возможно, текст проходит два преобразования? на всякий случай проверь и `.. LIKE \\\%%(mark)s\\\%; ..`

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, возможно это костыль, но, во всяком случае работает

```
cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM activities WHERE name LIKE %(mark)s;", {'mark': f'%{mark.lower()}%'})
```

Answer (score 0):

При необходимости использовать символ % в запросе используйте последовательность символов %%, например:
SELECT * FROM users WHERE bday_at LIKE '20%%'